# MongoDB Find like Lodash Find

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lodash, database

Is it possible for me to do something like this with a MongoDB query (I'm using MongooseJS as well).

In lodash, I can do [this](http://lodash.com/docs#find):

```js
var characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'blocked': false },
  { 'name': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'blocked': true },
  { 'name': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'blocked': false }
];

_.find(characters, function(chr) {
  // Do any kind of logic and ultimately return a boolean.
  return chr.age - 10 > 24;
}); // returns barney and fred
```

Can I do something like this with the built in mongo driver or mongoosejs? I would prefer to not read all the objects and iterate through them like this because there could be a lot of them. I would prefer mongo to do this for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not recommended for performance reasons (as it must iterate through every document and execute JavaScript without being able to use an index), you can use the `$where` operator ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)) to execute custom JavaScript code:

```
db.theCollection.find({ $where : "this.age - 10 > 24" })
```

(And I'm guessing the real logic would be more complex, as that query could be handled without using `$where`: `find({age: { $gt : 24 }})`. When possible, try to use the built in query operators as they are generally more efficient and it's often easier to utilize field indices.

Comment: Would this be faster than getting the whole collection and doing the logic with everything in node?

Comment: It probably would be. Probably depends a lot on system configuration, data requested, complexity of clause ...

Answer (score -1):

Lo-Dash iterates through elements and passes each of them to callback. It looks like it is not easy to do. It will require to create something very sophisticated that will be able to recognize conditions in callback function (parse it) and then try to use indexes and filter records with help of them.

MongoDB doesn't have such option.

Comment: MongoDB does have such an option. See my answer.

Comment: I agree but it still does not do any optimizations (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) and just do a full table scan. Probably $where could be used in combination with pre-filtered data.